# rvm showing bad pattern

Tags: rvm, zsh

I have rvm run on zsh and `rvm requirements` or `rvm install st` always return an error like this

> __rvm_parse_args:28: bad pattern: [[:alnum:]]*|@*

There is no problem when running on bash. How should I fix this?

Comment: try again - it can be possibly fixed

Answer (score 0):

open file `$rvm_path/scripts/cli` and change line 93 from

```
  [[:alnum:]]*|@*) # Commands, Rubies and Gemsets
```

to

```
  ([[:alnum:]]*|@*) # Commands, Rubies and Gemsets
```

in any case (it works or not) open a bug for rvm => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues